# Orthogonal Complement to arbitrary matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the orthogonal complement of the subspace

$$S = \{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^{4} \mid x + y = z + w = 0\}$$

I was working through some homework problems, stumbled onto this one and struggled with what to do.

So far, I have created an arbitrary matrix $A$ such that $A = (x,-x,z,-z)$ and I know that the orthogonal complement of $A$ is equals to the null space of $A$ transpose but I am struggling to find the nullspace of $A$ transpose with those arbitrary elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

You are almost there! Notice that $S = \text{span}\{(1,-1,0,0),(0,0,1,-1)\}$.

Considering that we are dealing with the standard inner product in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, $v = (a,b,c,d)\in S^{\perp}$ iff
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\langle v,(1,-1,0,0)\rangle = 0\\\\
\langle v,(0,0,1,-1)\rangle = 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I'm still a little confused on where to go from there...

Comment: @JohnSayle Are you aware of the notion of dot product?

Comment: yes I am, what would we do using that?

Comment: @JohnSayle At this case, you have the system: $a - b = 0$ and $c - d = 0$.

Comment: ohhhhh, so know we could say that the orthogonal complement to S would be a subspace of R4 where a - b = c - d = 0?

Comment: @JohnSayle Yes !

Comment: Awesome! thanks so much! also, I have more questions about my homework that you seem to be quite capable of answering, but stack wont let me post more than one question within 40 minutes, is there any way around this?

Comment: @JohnSayle You are welcome! I do not think so. Once you have posted the new question, please let us know what you have tried so we can better help you.

Comment: The new question is up! It is titled "Least Squares parabola with arbitrary elements".  Not to be pushy, but my homework is due in 11 minutes!

Comment: @JohnSayle I am sorry, but we are not here to make the homework for you. You should at least provide your efforts on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, since there are two free variables, $S$ is two-dimensional.  Since $\mathbb R^4$ is four-dimensional, we are looking for a two-dimensional space (since$S\oplus S^\perp\cong\mathbb R^4$).

But, also quite clearly, $(1,1,0,0)$ and $(0,0,1,1)$ are linearly independent elements of $S^\perp$.  Therefore they form a basis.